# Access Windows/Mac Shared Folder Locally With smb from iOS

Tags: ios, swift, local, shared, smb

I am trying to build an app where I am able to access(read/write) windows/mac shared folders in my local network with swift.

Is there any possible way to do that with swift?

There is an App in the App Store called "FileExplorer" https://apps.apple.com/de/app/fe-file-explorer-file-manager/id510282524 where you can access these shared folders, but I do not know how they programmed this and with which language.
I also tried to access my shared folders via this App and yes it worked I can see my shared folders on my Phone.

But there needs to be a way to do it with swift...

I already tried different things(code bellow). 
In the code bellow I tried to access the shared folder of my second mac and write the Text "Write this text to the fileURL as text in iOS using Swift" into the file named "Test.txt" and after that I want to read the same file again.

```
@IBAction func Button(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    var uc = URLComponents()
    uc.scheme = "smb"
    uc.user = "user"
    uc.password = "password"
    uc.host = "ip-adress"
    uc.path = "document-directory"

    // Save data to file
    let fileName = "Test"
    let url = uc.url
    //let DocumentDirURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/f/d/t/App/Assets/Apps/TestApp")
    let DocumentDirURL = try! URL(resolvingAliasFileAt: url!)
    let fileURL = DocumentDirURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("txt")
    print("FilePath: \(fileURL.path)")


    let writeString = "Write this text to the fileURL as text in iOS using Swift"
    do {
        // Write to the file
        try writeString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed writing to URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }



    var fullString: String = "" // Used to store the file contents
    do {
        // Read the file contents
        fullString = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed reading from URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
    print("File Text: \(readString)")
}
```

If I run the code as shown, he always gives me the error
"smb scheme is not supported" and then some additional errors that he can not write/read the file because he can not access it.

When I change the code and only search on the device I am programming on and run the simulator to search for this file everything works fine. So I have problems with "smb".

Thank you for every helpful answer.

Comment: iOS doesn't support SMB natively.  You will need to implement this protocol yourself.  There is probably some source code out there you could use, but I doubt that there is anything in Swift.

Comment: Thx Paulw11, a few days ago I found this: https://github.com/amosavian/AMSMB2 I think this is what I am looking for, but i do not really know how to use it. I already implemented it in my project, but how do I use the first function? What should I write into the "handler" when I call that function

Comment: Did you tried to use Samba? this is an open source SMB solution written in C.
You can wrap this code and use it in your Swift project.
There is another C base SMB solution called YNQ, This is a commercial licence solution, the company name is Visuality Systems, you can contact them and ask.

Answer (score 2):

you can use amsmb2 library to do this

you can extend the template class provided to connect to download files, write files, list directories -> on an smb share

everything is asynchronous from memory, with the librarys calls including hooks for progress updates on the ui main thread etc

i believe the amsmb2  library function your after might be uploadItem

Answer (score 1):

iOS 13 includes SMB (server message block protocol) support

https://9to5mac.com/2019/06/17/ios-13-beta-2-enables-smb-server-connectivity-in-the-files-app/